# Why does the ModuleNotFound error message appear when i try to run openai on python?

Tags: python, openai-api, modulenotfounderror

When i try to run this code

```
import os
import openai
import tiktoken
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv
_ = load_dotenv(find_dotenv()) # read local .env file

openai.api_key  = os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEY']"
```

the error message Module not found appears for os openai and tiktoken even though i installed openai through CMD.

I tried to look online but no answers were particularly what i was looking for, i got the code from a free course on deeplearning.ai and i just cant get it to work.